# Hyperlinks in FlowDocumentScrollViewer are not working on the first click

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, flowdocumentscrollviewer

FlowDocumentScrollViewer scrolls to the top instead of triggering hyperlink click when we first click a hyperlink. Click is triggered by the second click as usual. This occurs when you click on hyperlinks after scrolling down.

`<FlowDocumentScrollViewer x:Name="fdsvSearch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="465" Document="{Binding markdownText, Converter={StaticResource TextToFlowDocumentConverter}}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ContextMenu="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></FlowDocumentScrollViewer>`

VerticalScrollBarVisibility disabled